# Unicode characters streamed as garbage characters using atmosphere

Tags: java, unicode, atmosphere

I'm facing problems while streaming some special characters using atmosphere framework.

Atmosphere version: 2.1.0-RC2

Java: 7

Some unicode characters like "Æ Ɑ   Ð   Ǝ   Ə   Ɛ   Ɣ   I   Ĳ   Ɩ   Ŋ   Œ   Ɔ   Ʊ   K‘  S   ẞ   Þ   Ʋ   Ƿ   Ȝ" are not streaming properly using atmosphere.

I'm setting AtmosphereResource CharacterEncoding to UTF-8 before streaming from server side.

```
res.setContentType("text/plain");
res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: how are these characters stored in application? in text files or in source code?

Comment: We are getting messages from a JMS Topic.

Comment: make sure that the non-ascii characters you receive are in the expected encoding, or else you'll have to convert the encoding upon text arrival

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with atmosphere framework, but as workaround I can suggest using library MgntUtils. That library has a Unicode encoder - decoder utility that can take any String and convert it into String of Unicode encodings in format \UXXXX and then convert it back. So you can convert your problematic Strings pass then as sequence of Unicode, and then convert it back. It helped me resolve and diagnose some tricky encoding issues. Here the links to the library: [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (jars, sources and javadoc API), [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.04%7Cjar) and finally an article that explains how to use those Utils in the library: [MgntUtils article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=pulse_spock-articles). In the article look for subtitle "String Unicode converter". It is very easy to integrate and use it.